# File handling for log with angular js $http

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, factory

I am developing a SPA in angular js and there is no server side language used, I just want to write a log txt file at server. I tried it using below factory code, but the data which i passed through this request needs a server side code to handle. How can i write a txt file directly with angular js $http without any server side script like PHP, node js etc?

```
.factory( "applicationLoggingService", ["$log","$window",function($log, $window){

                return({
                    error: function(message){
                        // preserve default behaviour
                        $log.error.apply($log, arguments);
                        // send server side
                        $http({
                            url: "log/logger.txt",
                            method: "PUT",
                            params: angular.toJson({
                                url: $window.location.href,
                                message: message,
                                type: "error"
                            })
                        });
                    },
                    debug: function(message){
                        $log.log.apply($log, arguments);
                        $http({
                            url: "log/debug_logger.txt",
                            method: "PUT",
                            params: angular.toJson({
                                url: $window.location.href,
                                message: message,
                                type: "debug"
                            })
                        });
                    }
                });
            }]
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you won't be able to do such thing without writing server side code. Your back end needs to handle the `PUT log/logger.txt`. I believe the only thing you could do without writing server code is write to a local file (a file in the client's computer).

Where's your app hosted? Why is writing server side code such an issue?

Comment: it is an issue because i am using a third party server to fetch database content through API provided by them, they don't allow me to write any server side code on there server, they have two log files present to maintain log, which is free for me to use but from client side. i hope you understand

Comment: than why don't you write log on your own server where this angular code resides. You have permission to write on your own server.

Comment: @RajuJain i got your concept, but issue here is this angular code will be work as an Ipad application in ipa mode, so there is no server for angular files, we compressed this into ipa file using phonegap. So only possiblity to manage log is on third party server which provide us API's. It is clear now ?

Comment: Are you able to save new data in that third party server? You can create another table for logs and save it as if it were another entity... Does it make sense?

Comment: What API calls are available to you? How do you retrieve the database contents?

Comment: It is something like Facebook API, it is official API's so i am not able to disclose url here. From this api i got users, list of there post etc. I have all the API through which i got data for reading purpose and not allow any edit/insert and delete operation